# Deserialize JSON that has variables in it

Tags: c#, json

I have some JSON like this:

```
{ address: EMAIL_FROM }
```

And I'd like to serialize it - using C# - into a class like this:

```
class Email {
    public string address {get;set;}
}
```

The issue is resolving the variable 'EMAIL_FROM' into a value as part of the deserialisation. Are there any tools out there which let you supply a callback function which would be passed the string `"EMAIL_FROM"` as a parameter, and return the value of the variable, which would then get injected into the address field on the Email object?

Comment: I assume your are talking about a JSON serializer. There are plenty of options out there, simply search google

Comment: Where is defined the `EMAIL_FROM` variable?

Comment: @Yuval - I have found plenty of serializers, but they all expect the JSON to use literals in the field values. I want a serializer which can be supplied with a resolver which resolves non-literals (i.e. variables)

Comment: @Alberto - the EMAIL_FROM variable needs to be resolved to a value. I want to be able to supply the serializer with a resolver (such as a callback) so that the variable can be resolved to a value when parsing the JSON

Comment: I don't think you can instruct the serializer to do this kind of things. But you can always use string.replace: `"{ address: EMAIL_FROM }".Replace("EMAIL_FROM", "pluto")` and then deserialize

Comment: Bare variables like `EMAIL_FROM` are not valid values in standard JSON (see [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)).  Therefore, it is unlikely that you will find an existing JSON parser that supports resolving them.  You will probably have to craft your own solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for all comments... in the end I had to do Alberto's suggestion - do the string replace first, then use a standard deserialiser to deserialise the resulting string into an object. If anyone ever discovers a nice tool that fits the bill, please add a comment!